# The double partial derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a differential of a function, $df(x,y)=y\sin(xy)\mathrm{dx}+x\sin(xy)\mathrm{dy}$.

How do I determine the double partial derivatives $f_{xy}, f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$?

I am fairly certain I have to use the chain rule, but I can't see how to apply because of the $y$ and $x$ in the front.

If it's true that I should use the chain rule, could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Given**
$df(x,y)=y\sin(xy)\mathrm{dx}+x\sin(xy)\mathrm{dy}$

**By Using**
$df(x,y)=f_{x}\mathrm{dx}+f_{y}\mathrm{dy}$

**We can get that**
$f_{x}=y\sin(xy)$
$f_{y}=x\sin(xy)$

**From there:**
$f_{xx}=y^{2}\cos(xy)$,
$f_{yy}=x^{2}\cos(xy)$
$f_{xy}=\sin(xy)+xy\cos(xy)$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how you get $f_{xx}$ and $f_{yy}$, but why don't you get $f_{xy}=xy\cos(xy)$?

Comment: @dexterity: Because $f_{xy}=(f_{x})_{y}$, it should derivate about $y$ to $y\sin(xy)$, note that $y\sin(xy)$ is a product of two functions of $y$, then you should use Lebniz rule.

Comment: This answer seems to me to be "too much of an answer" for a homework question.  I thought we were only supposed to give hints?